# jQuery scrollTo() not working in angular 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

I'm using a library called [ng2-pdf-viewer](https://github.com/VadimDez/ng2-pdf-viewer) for some reason the default way to stick to a page isn't working, so what I've done is I've used jQuerys `scrollTo()` method to scroll to the the `.page` class in the PDF so if I wanted the page to be scrolled to page 2 it would be page `.page:nth-child(2)` now I've got this working.. but only after you refresh the page and not when you first land on the page so If I follow a link to my pdf-view page it doesn't scroll but then when I refresh the page it does.. now I'm not sure if using jQuery scrollTo is the best method but its the only way I've been able to kind of get it to work

HTML

```
<pdf-viewer [src]="pdfSrc"
          [render-text]="true"
          [autoresize]="true"
          [original-size]="false"
          style="display: block;" (after-load-complete)="callBackFn($event)">
</pdf-viewer>
```

COMPONENT.TS

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';
import { AppConsts } from '@shared/AppConsts';
import { AppComponentBase } from '@shared/common/app-component-base';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { HeaderTitleService } from '@shared/service/headerTitle.service';


declare var jQuery: any;
const $ = jQuery;


@Component({
  selector: 'app-pdfview',
  templateUrl: './pdfview.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pdfview.component.less']
})



export class PdfviewComponent implements OnInit {


pdfSrc: string;
pdf: string;
pageNum: number = 2;
botString: string;
pageNumberVar: string;


@Output() notify: EventEmitter<String> = new EventEmitter<String>();

constructor(
   private route: ActivatedRoute,
   private headerTitleService: HeaderTitleService
) {
this.pdf = route.snapshot.params['pdfId'];
  if (this.pdf === '1') {
      this.pdfSrc = '../../../assets/pdf/emeds1.pdf';
      this.botString = 'Admission Reconciliation loaded on Page 2 - matching the word ‘reconcile’ for you.';
      this.pageNumberVar = '2';
    } else if (this.pdf === '2') {
      this.pdfSrc = '../../../assets/pdf/medrec.pdf';
      this.botService.sendMessage('I have loaded the document on page 21 showing "Medication Reconciliation"');
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.botService.sendMessage('That saved you hours of reading :)'); 
       }, 2000);
      setTimeout(() => {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $('.page:nth-child(29)').offset().top
         }, 300);
       }, 1000);
    }
  }


  callBackFn(pdf: PDFDocumentProxy) {
  this.botService.sendMessage(this.botString);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(function(){
     $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $('.page:nth-child(' + this.pageNumberVar + ')').offset().top
   }, 300);
   }, 1000);
   }
}
```

as you can see above ive tried putting the scrollTo function in `ngAfterViewInit` but that didnt fix it either

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, I believe that it is not a good idea to use jQuery with Angular, since it accesses the browser's DOM directly, bypassing Angular's (emulated) Shadow DOM.

In this case, I think that you can probably do away with your scrollTo fix, and just get the pdf viewer working properly.

I initially had problems with showing the correct page too, but after trying a few things, came up with this working configuration:

```
<pdf-viewer [src]="pdfSrc"
            [(page)]="page"
            [show-all]="false"
            [rotation]="0"
            [zoom]="0.9"
>
</pdf-viewer>
```

I would start with this, making sure that you get the proper page rendered, and then add your other properties, one at a time, to see what works and what breaks.

Comment: hmm I got it to go to the 2nd page, but when I put show-all back on it no longer works, I need to be able to show the whole document and it start on the page i specify

Comment: I haven't tried it, but looking at the source code of the library's demo app, I suspect that you'll need to set `stick-to-page` to true for that to work